# How to get the value of an ID TR from td value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this data in a table:

```
Red
Green
Blue


Yellow
Pink
Orange
```

I want to show an alert like this:

```
alert($(this).closest('tr').find("Orange").text());
```

But it does not work.

Comment: show your html code please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: <table id="Colours"><tr id="1">
<td>Red</td>
<td>Green</td>
<td>Blue</td>
</tr>
<tr id="2">
<td>Yellow</td>
<td>Pink</td>
<td>Orange</td>
</tr>
</table>

Answer (score 0):

set an id field for each tr like

```
<tr id="1">
<td>Red</td>
<td>Green</td>
<td>Blue</td>
</tr>
<tr id="2">
<td>Yellow</td>
<td>Pink</td>
<td>Orange</td>
</tr>
```

then
alert($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));

Comment: Thanks sir, but I want to get TR ID if TD = Orange, and the value I want is ID TR is 2, can help me?